# Laravel - saving multiple models

Tags: php, laravel-4, pivot-table

Hy guys, i have a post table and a tags table also a post_tag pivot table in my DB.

Everything works just fine, when i want to save a new post with one tags using this method:

```
$post->tags()->save($tag)
```

But when i have multiple tags, then of course the save method dies.
So my question is how can i save multiple tags ?

Answer (score 0):

If your `$tag` is an array you can try something like:

```
$tags = array(1,2,3,4);

$post->tags()->attach($tags);
```

The above method will add a `tag_id` 1,2,3,4 for that particular post.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use the [`saveMany()`](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models) method which allows you to store an array of models.

```
$post->tags()->saveMany($arrayOfTagObjects);
```

I think that method is more straightforward since you pretty often work with collections (which you can easily convert into an array) or arrays anyways. So you don't need to extract the id's by yourself.